# Has Batman ever had a brother?

Tags: dc, batman

This contains SPOILERS for recent Batman comics (*Batman* #10).

> In *Batman* #10 by Scott Snyder and Greg Capullo, it is revealed that mayoral candidate Lincoln March is both a member of the Court of Owls and also, allegedly, Batman's younger brother (Thomas Wayne Jr.). The backup story in the issue shows a flashback decades in the past, when Bruce Wayne was only 3 years old. The flashback shows events that Lincoln March referred to in the main story. When Bruce was 3, his mother was in a car accident while pregnant with Thomas Wayne Jr. (the accident occurred at the corner of Lincoln St. and March St. to boot!). He was then born early and put into a childcare facility where he remained after his parents were murdered. Therefore, Bruce never knew he had a brother.

Does any of this exist prior to the [New 52](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/The_New_52)? Does it exist post-[Crisis](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Crisis_on_Infinite_Earths), or is this all Golden and Silver age mythology?

Comment: [Thomas Wayne Jr.](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Thomas_Wayne,_Jr._(Earth-One)) <--

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, as [The Doctor](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/18325/has-batman-ever-had-a-brother#comment33990_18325) noted in his comment there was a [story](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Thomas_Wayne,_Jr._%28Earth-One%29) on Earth-1:

> Thomas Wayne, Jr. suffered severe head injuries when he was struck by a car as a young child. He was confined to a mental institution.

The [note](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Thomas_Wayne,_Jr._%28Earth-One%29#NotesEdit) contains this information though:

> This version of Thomas Wayne, Jr. (Earth-One), including all history and corresponding appearances, was erased from existence following the collapse of the Multiverse in the 1985-86 Crisis on Infinite Earths limited series and is now considered apocryphal.

Since the the same back story of the car wreck as a young child is there we can surmise that the writers are taking that original story idea and adapting it for the New 52.

Answer (score 7):

**Yes, okay, let me rephrase that. Since his erasure from history in the Earth 1, "Wipe the Blood off My Name," Pre-Crisis story (World's Finest Vol 1 223.) Thomas Wayne, Jr. has never existed, again.**

Okay, that's not quite true either, since the Earth-3, Owlman is technically Thomas Wayne, Jr. as well (though on Earth-3 there was no Batman). So I guess what some writer did was to take the mentally deranged one-shot throw-away idea in World's Finest and combine it in some mutant experiment with the Earth-3 villain for the modern version of Thomas Wayne, Jr.

Since they are taking the opportunity to reshuffle the DCnU, I guess some writer took advantage of how little background story there was about the Waynes and found a way to sneak in a younger Thomas Wayne, Jr. The premise however, is weak, since it is likely Alfred would have known about the younger Wayne and insisted on taking care of him as well.

Ah, continuity, thy name is retcon.

Comment: Certainly I agree that Alfred would have at least been aware of him, and would have informed Bruce about his existance.

Comment: Couple years late, I know, but the accident happened BEFORE Alfred became the butler. In fact, it tied directly into the events leading up to his arrival.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in a comic with a character named Deadman who was a circus performer before his death and could now enter bodies and control them. Thomas Wayne Jr. was in a mental institution but got out. He became known as the Boomerang Killer. Deadman took over his body for a while after Batman defeated him.